Chrome incorrectly reporting a CA-Signed SSL Certificate as invalid due no Subject Alternative Names specified
Hello Stack Overflow Users.
I've recently setup an IIS based webserver running on a server that is joined to my Windows Domain.
I want to view the webpage from multiple domain joined client PCs, but don't want the "your connection isn't private" popup in Google Chrome etc.
After generating a certificate via my Windows CA server, Chrome is complaining that a SAN was not specified but after looking at the certificate I can see one is specified.
To attempt to fix this, I've generated a .CSR file on my IIS server with the following attributes:
CN = FQDN of IIS server
C  = GB
L  = My locality 
O  = My company name
Certificate Subject Alternative name = 192.168.0.XX (IP address of server

adding the SAN as IP address
The .CSR generated via All Tasks --> Advanced Operations --> Create Custom Request from the Certificates snap-in within mmc.exe
I've then logged into my Windows CA server and gave it the previously generated .CSR file by opening a CMD window and running the following command:
`certreq -attrib “CertificateTemplate:WebServer" `

The certificate is then generated and I exported it as a .PFX and then imported it to IIS.
After importing it to IIS I changed the binding to use the new CA signed certificate instead of the self-signed one.
When I go to the IIS based webpage in Chrome I can see that the certificate has updated, as I can see it has the attributes mentioned earlier and the publisher is listed as my CA server.
For some reason, I'm still getting the Chrome error of:
This server could not prove that it is FQDN; its security certificate does not specify Subject Alternative Names. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.
Chrome error
When I view the Certificate in the Chrome browser I can clearly see a SAN is defined as an IP address - is it possible that an IP address isn't valid and it's actually looking for a hostname?
SAN defined
Any help would be massively appreciated.
Thanks.

@SteffenUllrich Correct, I'm trying to access the webpage from the FQDN as this will be the norm for anyone on the domain who needs to access it.
The reason for adding the IP address as a SAN was so if I ever need to access it over an IP address, then ideally it shouldn't complain about the cert being invalid.

CN is obsolete and will not even be considered anymore by many clients (like everything derived from Chrome). You need to add both the FQDN and the IP as SAN.

@SteffenUllrich That makes sense, thank you for your help.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6125#section-6.3

Security Warning: A client MUST NOT seek a match for a reference
identifier of CN-ID if the presented identifiers include a DNS-ID,
SRV-ID, URI-ID, or any application-specific identifier types
supported by the client.

Once you have a SAN extension, the subject CN isn't matched any more.  If you're seeing the subject CN being used as a match in browsers other than Chrome, it just means that their implementation of name matching doesn't consider an IP-Addresses-Only SAN as triggering this clause; but clearly Chrome does.
Just fix your creation process to copy your CN value into the SAN when building the certificate.

"Once you have a SAN extension, the subject CN isn't matched any more. " - Chrome will not consider CN at all, no matter if you have SAN or not.
